# frame type/Control Byte of the ISO8583

Tags: controls

I would like to know what is this control byte or frame type in ISO8583. I have no idea if both words results same meaning or not.

I am working on ISO 8583-1993 message format and I was asked if it is suported by my system.

**Sample Frame type :**
L2 L1 0 0 
First 2 bytes – length of the package body as a binary sequence, upper byte is first, two binary zeros, package body

Answer (score 0):

I understood from someone that frame type in ISO8583 means the message format.
ex :

This format is called frame type.